# Issue with ./gradlew clean using react native android

Tags: java, react-native

Within my app, I run `cd android` and then `./gradlew clean`.

I then get a `BUILD FAILURE` error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper

 * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED.

I swapped the value of the  `distributionUrl` within the gradle-wrapper.properties file with this value `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME`